# Django REST Framework: POST Request: How to save data only if the data doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new in Django and I'm stuck on the following problem:

I have the following code:

models.py:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='votes', null=True)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
class VoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    ]
    serializer_class = VoteSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

serializer.py:

```
class VoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        fields = ('id', 'answer', 'user')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        answer = validated_data.get("answer", None)
        poll = answer.poll
        return Vote.objects.create(answer=answer, poll=poll, user=user)
```

Each time I do a POST Vote request a new Vote is created.

But I would like to check if the user has already voted for the poll.

I have this code but I don't know where to put it:

```
if not poll in [vote.poll for vote in user.votes.all()]:
    # Create Vote
```

How to correctly check if the user has already voted in the poll and if not, create a vote?

Comment: Is one user not allowed to vote more than once?

Comment: each user can vote in each poll only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easy solutions is, settings a **`unique_together`** constraint in the Meta section. If you do so, Django and DRF will take care of that.

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='votes', null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'poll')
```

Alternatively, you can use [**`UniqueConstraint`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint)

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='votes', null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('user', 'poll'),
                name='your constraint name'
            )
        ]
```

Comment: But won't this "unique_together" attribute allow people to vote with different options?

Comment: What you mean by "*different options*"? Let us consider Stackoverflow, we can't vote an answer more than once.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have a Poll with differents Answer. I want to allow user to vote only once to each Poll. I tried `unique_together=('poll', 'user')` but it doesn't work. I edited my question too

Comment: Updated the answer. Just add `poll` to the rest of the fields

Comment: Yeah that stackoveflow for example. There are two types of "vote" (update or downvote). Your way of making answer and user unique together would allow me to vote upvote and downvote the same time.

Comment: Your unique fields should be just user and poll. Adding answer to the unique field would allow a user to vote multiple times with all the different options/answers

Comment: Yes it's work with `unique_together=('user','pool')`. A last question: when I tried to add a poll with a user who had already voted, I get the 500 error  'UNIQUE constraint failed'. I would like an 400 error instead. How can I do that ?

Comment: AFAIK, `unique_together` validations are handled by DRF serializer by default and it will give you an HTTP 400

Comment: You can remove your **`create(...)`** method as it doesn't provide any additional functionality than buit-in